# String to Array formatting

Tags: php, strings, array

I'm tying to convert from this formatted string:

```
$filtersStr = "id:1||name:alex";
```

to:

```
['id' => 1,'name' => 'alex']
```

My solution for now:

```
foreach(explode('||', $filtersStr) as $filter){
            list($k, $v) = explode(':', $filter);
            $filters[ $k ] = $v;
        }
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the amazing [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function. It does everything you need. But you are using different delimiters for `key => value` pairs. If you change those to `&` and `=`, you can do like this:

```
$filtersStr = 'id=1&name=alex';

parse_str($filtersStr, $filters);
```

And `$filters` will have what you want. But that's not the case, so, one could do this:

```
parse_str(
    str_replace(
        array('%', '=', '&', '||', ':'),
        array('%26', '%3D', '%26', '&', '='),
        $filtersStr
    ),
    $filters
);
```

The characters `%`, `=` and `&` will have a special meaning. They have to be replaced with their URL-codes. `parse_str()` works on URL-encoded strings and leaving those characters unchanged would cause all sorts of bugs. The order of the elements in the array is **VERY** important.

Here's how it works:

- Replace `%` by `%26`
  It must be the first of you will be replacing `%` everywhere and break it
- Replace `=` by `%3D`
  This guarantees that no meaningful `=` will be replaced
- Replace `&` by `%26`
- Replace `||` by `&`
- Replace `:` by `=` 
  At this point, your `'id:1||name:alex'` will be `'id=1&name=alex'`
- Hand it over to `parse_str()`

And done! I prefer the first method instead of this *kludge*. Use this second one with extreme care!

---

In a comment, it was explained that it's usage was like this:

```
/arena?filter=id:1||content_name:alex&anotherParam=smth
```

If you can change the URL, throw this whole code away and do like this:

```
/arena?filter[id]=1&filter[content_name]=alex&anotherParam=smth
```

This will have the **exact** structure you wish. Simply use `$_GET['filter']` to access all values. And done! An alternative with 0 lines of code!

Comment: this have to be one parameter in url like /arena?filter=id:1||content_name:alex&anotherParam=smth

Comment: Yep get to this 5 min ago but thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing the structure on string formatting, then I'd suggest considering JSON as a better alternative.

It's a better alternative than [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), because, its support is inbuilt into many languages, including PHP with the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) functions.

---

Consider this:

```
$object = ['id' => 1,'name' => 'alex'];
$JSON = json_encode($object);

$DAL->do_whatever($JSON);
```

or:

```
$JSON = $DAL->retrieve_whatever();
$object = json_decode($JSON);

buildProfile($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives are good because we find the solution handy, which are well described by @Quill and @Ismael,

If you have decided to go with the current format of your string, here is the alternative i wrote,

```
foreach(explode('||', $filtersStr) as $val)
{
    $filters[strtok($val, ':')] = trim(strstr($val, ':'), ':');
}   unset($val);
```

Here `strtok($val, ':')` will stop at first `:` it encounters, in our case it will be `id` and `name`, so no `:` will be in final array keys.

`strtok($val, ':')` will get the whole string after first `:` it encounters and `trim` will clear suffixed `:`s.

The benefit is that when it encounters values like,

```
$filtersStr = 'id:1||name:alex:mercer';
```

It outputs **as is**,

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => alex:mercer
)
```

Other results are same.